# TypeSafe config in tests (Could not resolve substitution to a value)

Tags: scala, typesafe, typesafe-config

All,

I am using the HOCON based typesafe config in a project.

This is a `Scala` project, and we are striving for 100% test coverage.

I have two *test* configs: `test1.conf` and `test2.conf` ... here is the code for loading

```
object TypeSafeTestConfigProvider {
  System.setProperty("foo","value")
  System.setProperty("bar","value")
  val config1 = ConfigFactory.load("test1.conf")
  val config2 = ConfigFactory.load("test2.conf")
}
```

neither `foo` nor `bar` can be resolved for some reason **if** I run a single test ... yet they resolve without an issue if I run all my tests together ... which is very inconvenient.

It appears the `ConfigFactory` class takes a static snapshot of `System.properties` and future changes to System properties are not reflected in the resolution process.

How would you recommend I setup my tests?

Comment: How do you reference this `TypeSafeTestConfigProvider` when you run a single test?

Comment: `import TypeSafeTestConfigProvider.config1`

Comment: my colleague found that running `invalidateCaches()` fixes the problem ... weird ...

Comment: I had the same problem. It is normal if other tests are launched before and load config so invalidateCaches is usefull in that case.

Answer (score 0):

`com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory.invalidateCaches();` did the job for me. Playing with System Properties in unit tests is a Pain.